# Excel VBA code to add an extra row

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am creating VBA code in Excel to add a row and format it.

I need the value for "i" to be a variable (instead of 20 as shown) depending on the number of entries in the first column of my Excel sheet.

```
Sub NextLine()

'
' AddLine Macro
' Adds Line

Dim i As Integer
i = 20

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select '1 row down
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=1
    Range("$A$1:$M$" & i).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlHairline
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlHairline
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlHairline
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlHairline
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlHairline
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlHairline
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$M$" & i

End Sub
```

Comment: `i` is a variable. You declared it as an integer type with `Dim i as Integer`. The only reason why `i` is set to 20 is because you told it to be with `i = 20`. if you want `i` to equal something else, then assign it a different value `i = somethingThatReturnsAnInt32Value()`

Comment: Are there blanks between the entries? I.E., do you want to find the "last entry before the first blank" or the "last entry anywhere in column A" ?

Answer (score 2):

Replace the line:

```
i=20
```

with:

```
With ActiveSheet
    i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
End With
```

It counts the number of rows with data on column A.

By the way, I tested your macro and it doesn't add a row.